# battery draining issue when widget is created for my app

Tags: android, android-widget

In my application I used the widget creation code for displaying alerts every 10 minutes.
For updating the widget I need `WIFI`.
But when I run the application, it frequently gives the error time battery draining issue. Any suggestions?

Comment: Where does it show that message and how exactly are you specifying the update rate of your widget? More information required to help.